# Try-Catch doesn't catch Exception in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, try-catch

Some Android devices don't have the QualitySelector.getSupportedQualities() method and I need to catch this error to give it a proper quality. But the try catch does not catch the exception and the application hangs,

Capture code:

```
try{
            videoCapture = getVideoCapture()
            camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageCapture,videoCapture,preview)
            preview.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
        }catch(e : Exception){
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()
            videoCapture = getVideoCaptureSD()
            camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageCapture,videoCapture,preview)
            preview.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
        }
```

It is executed inside the bindPreview() method in a Runnable

```
cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
    val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
    bindPreview(cameraProvider)}, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
```

Even now change the implementation, create an Executor and add it to the setSurfaceProvider method

```
    private val executor = Executor { command ->
    command?.let {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            try{
                val job = async(SupervisorJob()){it.run()}
                job.await()
            }catch (e : Exception){
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I did it the normal way and it didn't work for me, I did it with coroutines to be able to control the job but I didn't get the exception either :(

```
preview.setSurfaceProvider(executor, binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
```

Comment: I can't find any listing for a function with that name anywhere in Android.  If it's some library you're using, list it.  Also, if its an android SDK function that doesn't exist on older devices, the proper way to avoid it is to version check with an if before calling it rather than catch an exception.

Comment: @GabeSechan QualitySelector.getSupportedQualities()
from camerax videoCapture.
the phone has Android 11.
But the hardware is very bad.
It is one of the new and cheap samsung versions.
I already got a way to control the error, the thing is that the try{}catch doesn't work for me

Comment: An uncaught exception wont hang the program—it will crash it. Step through this code line by line in the debugger with a breakpoint in the catch block to see what’s actually happening.

Comment: So the version doesn't matter, it its in AndroidX, that library is part of your app.  Most likely you have a threading problem.  You're doing a blocking get on a future, that's almost always a mistake.  Most likely your thread is waiting for that call to return, but that call is set to run on the same thread thus deadlock.

Comment: @GabeSechan I even changed the implementation with an executor and it still doesn't work for me :(, look at the code, the error appears in setSurfaceProvider, which inside is executed in a thread and I think that's why I can't control the exception

Comment: Like @Cypherdare said-  an uncaught exception doesn't hang, it crashes.  If you're hanging, its a threading deadlock issue.  Or possibly an async operation never finishing.

Comment: I guess you are using webrtc or something. I also guess that you are not getting crashes because the webrtc method has handled exceptions in their code. These all are my assumptions only.